# Variables contains html tags display tags

Tags: html, variables, smarty

I have a variable contains html tags when i print it in tpl file. It shows html tags too.

in php file

```
$content=" < h1>Header< /h1>< p>Content< /p>"; 

$this->assign("content", $content);
```

in tpl file

```
{$content}

displays: < h1>Header< /h1>< p>Content< /p>`
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use spaces in your html tags between `<` and the tag item, just use this: `<h1>`.

This is good code for you:

```
$content = " <h1>Header</h1><p>Content</p>";
```

Comment: start with something simple: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables

if this doesn't work, check your install of smarty

Comment: Data exists in db in this way so i have to use it like this. Also my install looks fine

Comment: If also Stefan code displays HTML tags, you have to check if you are using a Smarty **[variable filter](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.filter.tpl)**. Try this: `{$content nofilter}`. If it works, you have some kind of varible filter setted.

Comment: Still display <h1>Important Safety Information</h1>
<p style="padding: 4px;">
Serious infections, .....